# Modify x-axis labelling (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I would like to change the 1,2,3,4,5 on the x axis to other strings that would describe the plot better on the x axis. That way I would not have to add a legend into the plot.

Is that possible?

[image]

Comment: Hi again! I've noticed you have a lot of questions with answers that are not accepted. It's a nice way to reward people to accept the best answer, vote, give feedback.

Answer (score 3):

The function you're looking for is [`xticklabels`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xticklabels.html).